# How to perform calculations in one query multiple conditions in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I tried to do calculations in one of my query tables as follows
[image: my db]

in laravel i try to do it like this

```
 public function index()
{
    $data = Answare::groupBy('questions_id')
    ->selectRaw("count(case when value = 'sangat buruk' then 1 end) as sangatBuruk")
    ->selectRaw("count(case when value = 'buruk' then 1 end) as buruk")
    ->selectRaw("count(case when value = 'baik' then 1 end) as baik")
    ->selectRaw("count(case when value = 'sangat baik' then 1 end) as sangatBaik");
    
    dd($sangatBuruk);
    return view('admin.jawaban.index', compact('data'));
    
}
```

in dd($sangatBurut) the result is:
[image: result dd]

how to make the final result like this
[image: final result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $statuses = Answare::toBase()
                ->selectRaw("count(case when value = 'sangat buruk' then 1 end) as sangatBuruk")
                ->selectRaw("//condition 2) as alias")
                ->selectRaw("//condition 3) as alias")
                ->first();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
     public function index()
{
    $data = Answare::groupBy('questions_id')
    ->selectRaw("count(case when value = 'sangat buruk' then 1 end) as sangatBuruk")
    ->selectRaw("count(case when value = 'buruk' then 1 end) as buruk")
    ->selectRaw("count(case when value = 'baik' then 1 end) as baik")
    ->selectRaw("count(case when value = 'sangat baik' then 1 end) as sangatBaik");
    
    dd($sangatBuruk); ---> **WRONG**
    dd($data); ---> **CORRECT**
    return view('admin.jawaban.index', compact('data'));
    
}
```

Ones you gotten the correct result then you can use the blade or livewire to show the data on the frontend. currently the content that you show is very limited unable to help other than point out what is wrong in the code.